# How to get parent parameter in nested route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I have the following basic structure of nested routes/components for a react app:

- `/users` `->` `UsersList`
- `/users/:id` `->` `UserLayout`

  - `/users/:id/` `->` `UserProfile`
  - `/users/:id/settings` `->` `UserSettings`
  - `/users/:id/blah` `->` `YetAnotherComponent`

What I'm trying to figure out, in the context of  react router v4, is how to access the `:id` parameter in the `UserSettings` component. I can access it fine in the `UserLayout` component, but nowhere else further downstream.

My main router definition lies in a `Home` component, but all the user-specific routes contain the same header information so I want all the user-specific routes to be nested. My current structure has these nested routes defined in the `UserLayout` component. However, no matter what I do to the layout component's route definition, I cannot get any other route than the "index" route (`UserProfile`) to render. When trying to access `UserSettings` or any other route, my top level 404 route gets hit instead.

Here's the relevant JSX (snippets of the actual components' `render` functions):

### Home

```
<main>
     <Switch>
         <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
         <Route exact path="/users" component={UsersList} />
         <Route exact path="/users/:id" component={UserLayout} />
         <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
         <Route component={NoMatch} />
     </Switch>
</main>
```

### UserLayout

```
<div>
     <Switch>
         <Route path={`${match.url}/settings`} component={UserSettings} />
         <Route path="/users/:id/blah" component={YetAnotherComponent} />
     </Switch>
     <Route path="/users/:id" component={UserProfile} />
</div>
```

In the `UserLayout` component I've tried both path formats shown in the `Switch` and have tried turning on/off exact matching. The only thing I can come up with is using the `Route` component's `render` parameter to pass the id parameter, but that just seems wrong. Is that my only option?

Comment: why not pass it down as a prop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course only a few minutes after I post, I figured it out. In my top-level route config, I had set the `/user/:id` to require an **exact** match. This meant that when I navigated to `/user/:id/anything_else` react router didn't load `UserLayout` at all and thus didn't get the chance to test the remainder of the routes I had configured.

So I changed this from my home component:

```
<Route exact path="/users/:id" component={UserLayout} />
```

...to this:

```
<Route path="/users/:id" component={UserLayout} />
```

... and now all is well with the world.